# How to debug C code with lldb in macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb

I was using `gdb` in Linux but now I have switched to Mac and read that `lldb` is the alternative to `gdb` in Apple devices. However, I'm getting an error when I try to use `lldb` (I also tried `gdb` but it does not recognize the files as executable). When I try to use it I get the following errors:

```
sanad@Sanads-MBP  ~/Desktop/cppLab  lldb ./a.out         ✔  623  01:43:54
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py", line 98, in 
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
```

…and a dozen more NameErrors exactly like this until the output ends with:

```
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

Comment: Looks like lldb uses Python, but it's not finding the Python module named "six" in the $PYTHONPATH. "six" is a well-known Python module for dealing with Python 2.x vs. 3.x compatibility issues. Try installing the "six" module on your system and make sure it's in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Try typing ``run``  after it and hit enter. See if your ``a.out`` start executing after that

Comment: I tried installing the "six" pakage but now it shows diffrent error .......lldb) target create "firstprog"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Current executable set to 'firstprog' (x86_64).

Answer (score 0):

lldb links to the System Python.framework, and can only load other python modules if they were built along with that Python library.  Turns out, the way Python works if you don't explicitly tell it where to find Python modules it will look alongside the "python" binary that it finds in your PATH.  So if you've installed another python and have it in your PATH, then lldb's python will try to load Python modules that won't actually load properly.  The current workaround is just to clear you hand-installed Python from your PATH environment variable in whatever Terminal window you want to run lldb from

This was recently fixed (r356819 on llvm.org) and will make it into the Xcode release in the near future.